# how to test if PHP system() function is allowed? and not turned off for security reasons

Tags: php, system, exec

I would like to know how to test if system() or exec() is allowed on a server. I keep getting this error "Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in ..."

I understand that the safe_mode function is depreciated in the php version my provider runs (5.3.3) so i cant use a get_ini('safe_mode') check.

What else to do?

I use this for a backup script. if the provider allows system, the script makes a tar file and mails it to me whenever a user logs in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, there's only two ways it can be disabled:  [`safe_mode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) or [`disable_functions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions).

So you can do a check like:

```
function isAvailable($func) {
    if (ini_get('safe_mode')) return false;
    $disabled = ini_get('disable_functions');
    if ($disabled) {
        $disabled = explode(',', $disabled);
        $disabled = array_map('trim', $disabled);
        return !in_array($func, $disabled);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Oh, and `function_exists` should return true, since it's a core function (otherwise you could forge a core function and cause some real havoc on a host)...  Therefore `is_callable` should also return true (since the function does exist).  So the only ways to tell, are to check the ini settings, or to actually call it...

**Edit:** One other thing to note, there are several of ways to execute shell commands.  Check out:

- [Program Execution Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)
- [Backtick Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Comment: Is this done using `disable_function()`  though? Because what the OP talks about also disables backticks.

Comment: @Pekka: The only two directives that I know of that effect `system()` and `exec()` are `safe_mode` and `disable_functions`.  So if it's not one, it must be the other.  And if it's neither, it should work...

Comment: @ircmaxell true, I can't find any other way, either. But does that mean that backticks remain enabled even if I disable `exec()`? Can't test right now, maybe later...

Comment: @Pekka: Yes.  The backticks are just a [language level alias](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) of `shell_exec`.  So they are available as long as `shell_exec` is (but if you add `shell_exec` to `disable_functions`, they will stop working)...

Comment: @ircmaxell ah, good to know! Thanks. One argument for actually trying to execute a command is if you want to be sure there is nothing else blocking execution (e.g. the [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) patch). If that is not an issue, this is the easiest way to go. +1

Comment: You are absolutely spot on with this function. THANKS.

Comment: The only thing is that this function returns true if the function is found in the disabled list. so you would want this function to return false in stead. so i changed the return in_array funtion into if(in_array(...)) return false;

Comment: @half-a-nerd: I spotted that error and edited it a little while ago to `return !in_array(...)`.  But nice spot either way...

Answer (score 3):

Testing for disabled functions and the presence of safe mode as shown by @ircmaxell is arguably the easiest way to go.

If you want to find out 1000% reliably whether execution of system commands is possible - there may be security patches like Suhosin that block this on another level - try to `exec()` an external command that is bound to work on all systems (including Windows), and is extremely unlikely to fail even if user rights are very tight.

Say

```
cd .
```

this should work (i.e. not return `false`, and return an error level code of `0`) at least on all Linux, Windows and Unix flavours including OS X.

Comment: Since both Linux and Windows have the `cd` command, `exec('cd .')` might be the best bet (it has no side effect, and should work on all systems)...  Otherwise, +1...

Answer (score 0):

function_exists() doesn't works for this situation ?

http://fr.php.net/function_exists

Comment: Nope.  It's a core function, so it will always exist.

Comment: no. in my test function_exists() and is_callable() both returned true. Which i can believe because exec and system both are valid function names and callable.

Comment: If they returned false, it would open the door to hosts (or attackers, etc) re-defining them and then sniffing for sensitive data (or worse)...

Answer (score 0):

[exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) returns false if it fails, or a success message string if it succeeds... so the following should work:

```
if(!exec('cd .')){ die('ERROR: Exec is not available!!!'); }
```

Replacement for 'cd .' can be any function you know to work on the system.