# shell_exec not working not able to convert pdftotext

Tags: php, linux, shell, cakephp, pdf

I am trying to convert a `pdf` file into text file. When I run the command through terminal its working fine but when try to execute it through `PHP` it's not working.

I am stuck in this situation from last four hour spend lots of time in google but no solution available. Can any body resolve this issue?

File owner - nobody

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/pdftotext /opt/lampp/htdocs/foldername/filename.pdf');
```

Can anyone provide any helpful solution?

I also tried to change `usr` folder ownership from root to nobody and provide 777 permission on folder and its context.

Comment: when you do shell_exec from PHP file you're under apache user, maybe apache has no permission in /usr/bin/pdftotext?

Comment: if you run it through `exec` and view the $output, what do you get? Should look something like: `exec('/usr/bin/pdftotext /opt/lampp/htdocs/foldername/filename.pdf',$output = array()); var_dump($output);`

Comment: NULL returns after execution

Comment: Maybe is permission denied.

Comment: you could `chown apache /usr/bin/pdftotext/` But before this, stop apache, `server httpd stop` then 'su apache` and check the command

Comment: actually, scratch that.. apache has no login permissions. Well just give persmissions with `chown`, google chown for more info

Comment: @AlexandruCalin nobody is my default apache user i set permission but nothing happens

Comment: I am trying code on my local system not on server. Please think about it.

Comment: By default, the folder `/usr/` is limited only to `root` access. In order for you to run your command as `nobody` or `apache` you would need to give permissions recursevly until you reach your `/usr/bin/pdftotext` which as i know it's not a good idea. So i think, `chown -R nobody /usr/bin/pdftotext`

Comment: nothing will happen i tried this too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23373/discussion-between-alexandru-calin-and-ajay-kadyan)

Comment: Are you running apparmor? Check /var/log/syslog to see if the command is being blocked.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels: No its not belocked. because other commands working fine.

Comment: wrong path: this `lamp` not `lampp` ;)

Comment: path is correct buddy its lampp not lamp

Comment: @AjayKadyan That's how AppArmor works, you can allow or deny running specific commands or accessing specific dirs and files when called from a specific other program. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels : so how I can check that check that its disabled or not?

Comment: You can disable AppArmor by running `sudo service apparmor stop` in the terminal. (Restart Apache after)

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels  didnt work

Comment: `setsebool -P httpd_execmem=1` in terminal

Comment: @World : setsebool not install returns when run this

Comment: Set `ini_set("display_errors", "on")` at the top of your php script and add this at the end of the shell command `2>&1` and post the output.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks now it works. Actually their is dependency of GCC_4.2.0 now it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command to run pdftotext is not correct.

There should be a second argument telling pdftotext to write to a specific file or just use a dash "-" to write to stdout, unless you actually want the program to create a text-file with the filename as the pdf (this would require write permissions in the /opt/lampp/.../ folder)

This is at least true for `pdftotext version 0.12.4`

> "Pdftotext  reads the PDF file, PDF-file, and writes a text file, *text-file*.  If *text-file* is not specified, pdftotext converts file.pdf
>   to file.txt.  If *text-file* is ´-', the text is sent to stdout."

So, the solution to your question would simply be add a dash after the filename, like so:

```
<?php
$pdftext = shell_exec('/usr/bin/pdftotext /opt/lampp/htdocs/foldername/filename.pdf -');
echo $pdftext;
```

Provided that the binary exists and PHP is allowed to use shell_exec and you have permissions and that the pdf-file exists and you have permissions.

Answer (score 2):

from [how to test if PHP system() function is allowed? and not turned off for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033841/how-to-test-if-php-system-function-is-allowed-and-not-turned-off-for-security)

```
function isAvailable($func) {
    if (ini_get('safe_mode')) return false;
    $disabled = ini_get('disable_functions');
    if ($disabled) {
        $disabled = explode(',', $disabled);
        $disabled = array_map('trim', $disabled);
        return !in_array($func, $disabled);
    }
    return true;
}
```

You may need to check if `isAvailable('shell_exec')`
On shared hosting this function might be disabled.

If it's not disabled, check the Apache log, it's all you can do.

Comment: he has access to terminal, i don't think it's shared hosting

Comment: For my Dreamhost account I also have console access. And, it's not a shared hosting. It depends... however, even if it's a private server, he needs to check "what can php do?". The terminal functionality is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

try exec and also make sure safe mode off in your php.ini file like this safe_mode = Off

```
exec('/usr/bin/pdftotext /opt/lampp/htdocs/foldername/filename.pdf')
```

also run this cmd in terminal to check if software is working

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a function disabled by many webserver, you can check:

```
var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions')); // not available if shell_exec disabled
var_dump(ini_get('safe_mode')); // not available if true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Since You are running Linux you may have a rights Problem

1. Check your file is owned by apache.

   chown apache apache file.php
2. Check youir file has rights

   chmod 644 file.php
3. Maybe check your sudoers file aswell
   [Sudoers ManPage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/visudo)