# Check if glob() is allowed

Tags: php, glob

I want to use `glob()` in a php script, but I got reports from users that it's not always allowed on the server. One user reported the following error:

```
Warning: glob() has been disabled for security reasons
```

How do I detect whether glob is allowed? Is this done via [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions), or are there other ways glob can be disabled? Does safe_mode also disable glob? (one commenter on php.net [says so](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php)).

Are there ways to reliably check if it's allowed other than checking safe_mode & disable_functions (as suggested in: [how to test if PHP system() function is allowed? and not turned off for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033841/how-to-test-if-php-system-function-is-allowed-and-not-turned-off-for-security))

Comment: Just try to execute it and catch the error.

Comment: Did you tried: `function_exists()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `glob` can be only disabled using the `disable_functions` ini setting. Use `function_exists()` to detect if it is available:

```
if(function_exists('glob')) {
    glob('...');
}
```

---

You can try it using this simple tests:

```
you@server ~ $ php -ddisable_functions='glob' -r 'var_dump(function_exists("glob"));'
bool(false)

you@server ~ $ php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("glob"));'
bool(true)
```

Comment: function_exists should return true, since it's a core function!

Comment: @Ewout According to [this code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#1359) it should return `false` for a disabled function.

Comment: It **is** working, meaning it returns `false`. Please try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for testing! I just want to make sure that it works accross different php versions so I cannot rely on just my own tests

Comment: actually it was a typo in your test (ddisable) that made it return false! It returns true for me: `php -disable_functions='glob' -r 'var_dump(function_exists("glob"));'`

Comment: @Ewout The double 'd' wasn't a typo :)

Comment: oops I see! `-d disable_funtions`

Comment: How about safe mode though? `php -d safe_mode=on -r 'var_dump(function_exists("glob"));'` returns `bool(true)` for me

Comment: @Ewout My PHP (5.5.9) doesn't support safe_mode anymore. However, safe_mode didn't disabled the `glob()` function, meaning your result - `bool(true)` - isn't surprising..

Comment: Good and working answer. Another way would be to use `ReflectionFunction::isDisabled`.

Answer (score 4):

The `glob()` function returns `NULL` if it's disabled, so:

```
if (($res = glob('*')) === null) {
    //try something else
} else {
    // $res should be an array or false
}
```

Btw, this won't prevent a warning from showing up; you can choose to either silence or ignore it altogether.

Comment: Depending on the php version, I believe it will also return NULL if the folder is empty

Comment: @Ewout Hmm, I think you may mean `false`.

Comment: I was going by the note on php.net: Note:
On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.

Comment: @Ewout Still think you meant `false` instead of `null` :)